# Auto-hiding navbar that works in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made an auto-hiding navbar and it works great in chrome, but IE11 freaks out. the idea is that when you scroll down it hides, but it reappears if you scroll up.  In IE11, I scrolled down and it hid the navbar. And then when I scrolled back up nothing happened for a second... and then the navbar appeared and disappeared 3 times in rapid succession... then a few seconds later it did it again.  Any idea what's wrong?

```
<script>
var lastScrollTop = 0;


$(window).scroll(function(){

   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
      $('#header').animate({ marginTop: '-70px', opacity: 0 }, 200);    
   } else {
         $('#header').animate({ marginTop: '0px', opacity: 1 }, 200);   
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Onscroll fires a bunch of times so you are telling it to animate a bunch of times.

Either stop the animation with stop()

```
$('#header').stop().animate(...);
```

or detect if it is animating.

```
$('#header').not(":animated").animate(...);
```

Comment: I tried both options and neither worked for me. thanks for the suggestions though

Answer (score 0):

I think should try not to use animate, scroll will catch actions multiple times, so replace with .css

Javascript:

```
$(function(){

    var start = 0;
    var end;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        end = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (end > start){
          $('#header').css({marginTop: '-70px', opacity: 0 });    
       } else {
             $('#header').css({ marginTop: '0px', opacity: 1 });   
       }
       start = end;
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
body{margin:0;height:2000px;}
#header{width:100%;position:fixed;height:70px;line-height:70px;background:red;top:0;left:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when I tried this and scrolled down in IE, the navbar goes away and comes right back

Comment: It works find in my IE 9 and 10 browsers. If you need more information you can read this https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c